How to add modules in Quill?
I would like to add an image resizer module, but I haven't succeed... Could someone please help me, and show me the right way to do this kind of things?

script :
<html>

  <head>

    <link href="https://cdn.quilljs.com/1.3.5/quill.snow.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <script src="js/quill.js"></script>

    
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="container" style="position:relative;">
    
      <div id="quill-editor" style="max-height: 300px"></div>
    </div>


<a href="js/modules/image-resize.min.js">
  

    <script type="text/javascript">

      
      var toolbarOptions = {
        container: [
          ['bold', 'italic', 'underline', 'strike'],
          ['blockquote', 'code-block'],
          [{ 'header': 1 }, { 'header': 2 }],
          [{ 'list': 'ordered' }, { 'list': 'bullet' }],
          [{ 'script': 'sub' }, { 'script': 'super' }],
          [{ 'indent': '-1' }, { 'indent': '+1' }],
          [{ 'direction': 'rtl' }],
          [{ 'header': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, false] }],
          [{ 'color': [] }, { 'background': [] }],
          [{ 'font': [] }],
          [{ 'align': [] }],
          ['clean'],

          ['link', 'image', 'video']
        ],
        handlers: {
   
        }
      }

      var quill = new Quill('#quill-editor', {
        modules: {
          "toolbar": toolbarOptions,
          imageResize: {
          displaySize: true
        },

    
        },
        placeholder: 'Compose an epic...',
        theme: 'snow',
      });
    </script>
  </body>

</html>


I get that error :

quill Cannot import modules/imageResize. Are you sure it was registered?
any help, please ?

Firstly, you can edit your question, so you could have added "Hello" rather than commenting. Secondly, in a Stack Overflow question, please focus one technical question only. If you have a problem with Quill not resizing an image, please post the simplest example that demonstrates Quill not resizing an image. Thirdly, if you have code to post, it improves readability to delimit the code using triple-back-ticks. You will see this explained on the right of the screen once you start editing.

To create a module in Node.js, you will need the exports keyword. This keyword tells Node.js that the function can be used outside the module.

Let see following code :-exports.functname=function(arg1,arg2,..) {
// function body
};

Hello Vijay, thanks, but  I  don't see the connection with Node, right ? ( I mean, to add amodule..  )
